# IndentationError: expected an indented block pygame pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

trying to create a game in pycharm using pygame and when ever i run the code for a test it comes back with this error message

def game_initialize():

IndentationError: expected an indented block

```
import libtcodpy as libtcod
import pygame

#game files
import Constants

def game_mian_loop():

    game_quit = False

    while not game_quit:

        #Get player input

        #Process input

        #draw game

    #quit game

def game_initialize():

    global SURFACE_MAIN

    pygame.init()

    SURFACE_MAIN = pygame.display.set_mode( (Constants.GAME_WIDTH,Constants.GAME_HEIGHT ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Loops can not be empty in Python. Use `pass` when want to do nothing for testing purposes.

```
while not game_quit:
    pass

    #Get player input

    #Process input

    #draw game
```